# Defining a function on the difference of two inputs

Tags: symbolic

Sorry if this is already on this forum somewhere, I had a look but couldn't find anything. Anyway, I am looking to define a function where the inputs are: `a` and `b-c`. Is there any way to do this?

MWE:

```
foo[x_Symbol,y_Symbol]:=z
foo[a_Symbol,(b_Symbol-c_Symbol)]:=foo[a,b]-foo[a,c]
```

The `(b_Symbol-c_Symbol)` is the output of another function that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already seems to work for me as you have it

```
foo[x_Symbol, y_Symbol] := z
foo[a_Symbol, (b_Symbol - c_Symbol)] := foo[a, b] - foo[a, c]

foo[x, y]
```

> z

```
foo[x, y - z]
```

> 0

Though perhaps you could give more details and we could see what you want to do with this code?

Comment: You know what, it is working for me now! Wasn't before... Thank you! No idea what happened there...

Comment: @DanielWilson-Nunn it was probably that you had an old `Downvalue` sitting around. It is generally a pretty good idea to `ClearAll[<your function name here>]` to make sure you don't have old definitions sitting around.

Comment: I always do a `ClearAll` before defining the function (I didn't in my MWE though) so I don't think it would have been that. But thank you anyway.